# Recording the path of non-recursive DFS without a hash table

Tags: algorithm, graph, depth-first-search

I am re-writing some of my graph search algorithms and I am a little stuck on DFS.  It seems like when using the call stack as your stack, returning the path from source to destination is easy -- simply return the nodes still on the call stack.

However, when implementing DFS iteratively I can't seem to figure out how to return the path.  I've stared at the patterns of push/pop, visited and current for a while now and I don't see how to do it.

I have seen some suggestions to use a hash table to store parent-child relationships, but surely this problem of returning paths doesn't require O(N) space.

Comment: just to confirm - are you using a stack in your iterative solution?

Comment: You can maintain array of parents[N] and once you go deeper with dfs from vertex i to vertex j you update your array parents[j]=i. Once you achieve your goal with dfs you can trace back whole path using this array and final vertex.

Comment: @leeor, yes i am using a stack

Answer (score 0):

You need to store only predecessor for current vertex. Then, you can restore your path using stack.

Pseudocode:

```
Repeat until you are not in the first vertex:
  Push to the stack current vertex;
  Go to the predecessor;
Your answer will be: current vertex, stack.pop(), stack.pop(), ... (until stack not empty)
```

Example:

Suppose, after DFS, you have found that:

```
pred[0] = 0;
pred[1] = 0;
pred[2] = 1;
pred[3] = 2;
```

and want to know the path from vertex 0 to vertex 3.

1. current = 3: stack = {3}, current = pred[3];
2. current = 2: stack = {3, 2}, current = pred[2];
3. current = 1: stack = {3, 2, 1}, current = pred[1];
4. current = 0: first vertex, finding the path now.
5. path = {0}, stack = {3, 2, 1}
6. path = {0, 1}, stack = {3, 2}
7. path = {0, 1, 2}, stack = {3}
8. path = {0, 1, 2, 3}, stack = {}
9. stack empty, return path: {0, 1, 2, 3}